# installing jforum on tomcat

Tags: tomcat7

I have put jforum in web app directory of tomcat
then i am calling
    "http://localhost:8080/jforum-2.1.9/install.jsp"
then error is coming

```
http://localhost:8005/jforum-2.1.9/install.jsp
```

HTTP Status 404 - /jforum-2.1.9/install.jsp

---

type Status report

message /jforum-2.1.9/install.jsp

description The requested resource is not available.

---

Apache Tomcat/7.0.32

please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check your Tomcat server. It should not redirect you to port 8005.

Answer (score 1):

As [jforum site](http://jforum.net/install.jsp) has been mentioned, you should check the following folders. I know that Zip package involves these folders where as the source code zip file does not.

1. `upload`
2. `tmp`
3. `images`
4. `WEB-INF/config`
5. `WEB-INF/jforumLuceneIndex`

Answer (score 0):

Try to rename your folder from jforum-2.1.9 to jforum. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

try this `http://localhost:8080/jforum/install.jsp`
default port of tomcat is 8080